# GQL issue with inequalities

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I'm building a Google App Engine app in PHP (the 5.5 runtime) using Google Data Store. As there is no official library for GDS in PHP, I'm using the Google PHP Client and the library found [here](https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds) so I have to use GQL for this. I'm familiar with SQL, and I understand GQL is very similar. So I'm trying to find all entities of type "post" with a latitude between two numbers.

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE latitude >= 37 AND latitude <= 39
```

I manually added the only entity of this type in the datastore. The latitude field is as follows:

```
latitude    A Number    Indexed    38.5617489
```

My GQL query should find this entity, right? I've gotten everything else to work thus far but this has stumped me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the query work if you only include latitude >= 37?

Comment: I guess my real question is if you defined latitude as an integer or a float?

Comment: In the PHP GDS Library, it's defined as a float. In the interface on Google's Developer Console, it's defined as "A Number". I assumed that this would be adequate to run inequalities against. Furthermore, I tried the query with 37.0 and 39.0. Does the interface not take care of casting it to a float? It should be able to guess it's a float with it having numbers to the right of the decimal and whatnot.

Comment: Since Datastore does not enforce specific datatypes itself, it can't assume you want to cast integers to floats. Did the query work when adding the decimals?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM post WHERE latitude >= 37.0 AND latitude <= 39.0` yields nothing.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your query. Does 'select * from post' return that row?

Comment: Excellent suggestion. It turns out that `SELECT * FROM post` returns an empty set.

Comment: The problem is that my data is in a namespace. Do you know how I can specify a namespace in a GQL query?

Comment: I see. Are you running this in the Cloud Console? There should be an 'options' button near the query input box that allows you to select a namespace? If you are doing this in code, there are methods to set the namespace before running the query.

Comment: Hello. The php-gds library (disclaimer: I am the author) should allow you to set a namespace on your Gateway constructor - some guidance is included in the docs here https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds/blob/master/README.md#multi-tenant-applications--data-namespaces